# Navigation menu item how to show on fragment

Tags: android

I want to show navigation menu item on fragment activity. there are 4 item of navigation item . I want to show it on fragment with list view. i want to show on  both navigation menu and fragment activity. after click showing same page individually.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/adviser"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person"
            android:title="Adviser" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/executive"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_group"
            android:title="@string/exce" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/member"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_people"
            android:title="@string/mem" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/alumni"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_school"
            android:title="@string/alu" />
    </group>


    <item android:title="Informations">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/aboutrudf"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_info"
                android:title="@string/abo" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

there's template for creating new activity click new > activity